Inductive proof that for all natural $n$ and all $d \leq n$, there is an element of $S_n$ of order $d$.
I tried to prove this with induction, but I can't figure out how to rigorously show that my $\tau$ really is of order $n+1$. How can I do this?

The statement has been shown for $n = 2$ (earlier in the text). 
Suppose that for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists an element of $S_{n}$ of order $d$ for all $d \leq n$. If $\sigma \in S_{n}$ is of order $d$, define
$$
 \widetilde{\sigma } : \{1, \dots , n+1\} \to \left\{ 1,\dots ,n+1 \right\} , \ m \mapsto \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
   \sigma (m), &\text{ if } m \leq n ;\\
  n+1, &\text{ if } m = n+1.
 \end{array}\right.
$$
Then $\widetilde{\sigma }$ is an element of $S_{n+1}$ of order $d$. If we can show that there is an element of $S_{n+1}$ of order $n+1$, we are finished. To this end, suppose $\sigma$ is an element of $S_n$ of order $n$. Define
$$
 \tau : \left\{ 1, \dots , n \right\} \to \left\{ 1, \dots , n \right\} , \ m \mapsto \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
  n+1, &\text{ if } m = 1;\\
  \sigma (1), &\text{ if } m = n+1;\\
  \sigma (m), &\text{ otherwise}.
 \end{array}\right.
$$
Then, $\tau$ is an element of $S_{n+1}$ of order $n+1$. This is because we add an extra "step": instead of getting sent from 1 to $\sigma (1)$, elements are first sent to $n+1$, before being sent to $\sigma (1)$.


By "r" OP mans "the new element $\tau$", I believe.

You're 90% of the way there. Rather than trying to construct that last element inductively, can you just look at $S_n$ and see an element of order $n$?

Ah yes, so let $\tau (1) =n$ and $\tau(k)=k-1$?

That'd work. My own approach was the inverse of that. :)

Thank you for your hint!
